# Display thumbnail only on the very first post in the loop?

Tags: post-thumbnails, loop

What's the best way to use `<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>` in my loop **BUT** only show a thumbnail on the FIRST post? Meaning, only the first post in the loop will have it's image shown?

**Here is an example of a loop that shows the image for ALL posts:**

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<!-- Display the posts Image thumbnail for the post -->
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
 <!-- Display the date and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
 <!-- Display the Post's Content in a div box. -->
 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- add a variable before the loop (before the while), for example $first = true;
- add a check inside the loop for this variable
- after the use, change the flag

Code:

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php $first = true; ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<!-- Display the posts Image thumbnail for the post -->
    <?php if ( $first ): ?>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
      <?php $first = false; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
 <!-- Display the date and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
 <!-- Display the Post's Content in a div box. -->
 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: I went with this solution as I found it most elegant and easy to understand.Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 4):

This code in your template will display the post thumbnail only for the first post:

```
<?php 
    ! isset ( $loop_first ) and the_post_thumbnail();
    $loop_first = 1;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would you not have to set $loop_first=0 or something afterwards?

Comment: @Pwn, The isset() saves you from creating a variable first.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use in my projects and it works well for me. I modified the code you provided to suit. Simply drop it in and it will display the post thumbnail only for the first post.

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php $i = 1 ; ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php if ($i == 1): ?>
<!-- Display the posts Image thumbnail for the post -->
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
<?php endif; ?>
 <!-- Display the date and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>
 <!-- Display the Post's Content in a div box. -->
 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
<?php $i++; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like it would work well too. I went with the above solution above instead because i found it simpler to use. Thank you for your time, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just check the `current_post` value

```
global $wp_query; // get the global query - works in custom queries too
if(0 == $wp_query->current_post){ /**is the first post**/ }
```